# Create a loop with normrnd with given mus and sigmas

Tags: matlab, for-loop, random

This is could be seen as an easy question but I could not figure out so far. I want to generate random number following a normal distribution, using given mus and sigmas, next round those numbers and eliminate the negatives. Finally store the created vectors in just one matrix called sim. The given mus and sigmas are the next ones:

```
m1=22.06;
s1=16.06;
m2=23.84;
s2=72.39;
m3=3.79;
s3=3.4;
m4=148.306;
s4=125.81;
m5=36.82;
s5=15.64;
```

So far I have the next code:

```
for i = 1: 5 
R(i) = normrnd(m(i),s(i),[m,n]);%generate random number ND
R(i) = round(R(i));
[badrows,c]=find(R(i)<0);%find negatives ones
newR(i) = R(setdiff(1:size(R(i),1),badrows),:);%eliminate them
sim(:;i)= newR(i);
end
```

I have tried the codes part by part and generate the random numbers, also round it and eliminates the negatives, but when I set the loop it has troubles calling the given numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to consider:

- You currently use `m` as both your mean and as the length of the first dimension of your R matrix. --> I have renamed your means to `mu`
- The size of `newR` will most likely be different for subsequent iterations, as you will be removing differing numbers of entries for which R<0. This is something `sim(:,i) = newR` will not like. --> I have made `sim` a cell.
- *newR* is two dimensional, which will cause you problems when eliminating values for which R<0 as it is unclear what the shape of the final matrix will be. --> I have limited this to the case of a vector
- I don't understand how you are eliminating the negative values --> I have used a more straight-forward approach.

  ```
  mu = [22.06, 23.84, 3.79, 148.306, 36.82];
  s = [16.06,72.39,3.4,125.81,15.64];

  m = 20;

  for i = 1: 5 
      R = normrnd(mu(i),s(i),[1,m]);
      R = round(R);
      R(R<0) = [];
      sim{i}= num2cell(R);
  end
  ```

Comment: It does exactly what I wanted. I realized that I used the same name for two differents things, my first mistake. Also I knew that newR will be changing its size because the elimination of negatives ones but, I thought that could be store like columns and not rows, regardless the length. My doubt is: If the allocating is  strictly necessary in rows form?

Comment: You can store them as columns, but you will probably encounter the same problem. To store them as columns try this: `R = normrnd(mu(i),s(i),[m, 1]);`

Comment: Thanks for your help!